# How can I configure protocol buffers to generate java classes within a given package?

Tags: java, protocol-buffers

I have a `.proto` file in my project. I would like to be able to compile the java source code with a predefined package. Is this possible? Is it even valid to compile protocol buffers in this way?

Comment: You can certainly define the package of the resulting interface code, by default it'll use whatever the `package` declaration says, but you can also use `option java_package = "com.something.whatever";` to tune the resulting package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can place the generated code under a predefined package.
As seen in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/javatutorial) , e.g. add

```
  package tutorial;

  option java_package = "com.example.tutorial";
```

to your `.proto` file. if the `option java_package` directive is present, the generated code is placed in the given package name. Otherwise the code is generated according to the `package` directive.